# python splinter webdriver can't start

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I've wrote a simple file `splinter_test.py`

```
    from splinter import Browser

    print("here")
    br = Browser()
```

When I run the code, it prints

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

I run with IDLE, but it prints the same in the command line.
It doesn't even gets to my `print("here")` statement.
Also, the `Browser` import doesn't work, i.e I can't use `b = Browser()`

Comment: I never got a webdriver working from IDLE there are some incompatibilities. Run your script from command line.

As for the print, you can try to flush the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you don't have "splinter" module installed in you pc. 
Just try this , go to run and start command prompt, in that put the following line

```
python -m pip install splinter
```

it will install it, I tried what you have written, it needs gecodriver in the path so go to this link "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.19.1/geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64.zip"
unzip it and put this file in the path.Done

Comment: Thanks. I do have splinter, when I write `import splinter` I see this message, and not import an error. And I actually try it with phantomjs too (I pass the parameters, and the executable path), and the same message is shown, so how is gecko driver going to work?

Comment: Geckodriver is needed to open the Firefox browser in you PC. So whenever the Browser() will be called it will call geckodriver.exe and it will open the firefox browser.